Провисания в моей игре на python, модуль pygame
В моей игре можно переключать 9 экранов с помощью кнопок. По какой-то причине когда камера пролетает над восьмым экраном игра резко начинает провисать.
Я пробовал уменьшать расстояние, с которого начинают прорисовываться "экраны" во время полёта камеры, но это не помогло. Также я пробовал вообще заменять картинку восьмого экрана на белый квадрат, но провисания остались. С чем это связано?
Расположить все файлы игры тут я не смогу, так как там много картинок, вот ссылка на github:
https://github.com/DeNaOl09/Restaurator.git
